# No repeats in a for loop with random.sample

Tags: python

I have the following:

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]

for i in range(3):
        print(random.sample(list1, k=1))
        print(random.sample(list1, k=1))
        print(random.sample(list1, k=1))
```

and am looking for something like:

```
['a', 'g', 'i']
['c', 'h', 'b']
['k', 'd', 'e']
```

The idea being to have no repeats anywhere.

I understand that I could slice the list if not using a loop, but am unsure of how to go about it with the loop involved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just shuffle it and take subsequent slices:

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]
random.shuffle(list1)

N = 3

for i in range(0, len(list1)-N+1, N):
    print(list1[i:i+N])

#['c', 'b', 'd']
#['i', 'e', 'j']
#['h', 'g', 'f']
```

Comment: That works perfectly.
If the number of strings within the list changes, is there a way to automatically adjust the range() to accommodate that?

Comment: Yep, check edit.

Answer (score 4):

Shuffle the list then break it apart:

```
import random

list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]
random.shuffle(list1)
for i in range(0, len(list1), 3):
    print(list1[i:i+3])
```

Comment: Holy s*** we put the exact same thing :) +1 for alacrity

Comment: @A.J.Uppal And the same for you :) It's the best way to do it

Answer (score 1):

You could also use you're original sample function and slice the list using list comprehensions:

```py
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]

output = random.sample(list1, k=9)
output = [output[i:i+3] for i in range(0,9,3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Input:

```
import random
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]

for i in range(3):
  print([list1.pop(random.choice(range(len(list1)))) for i in range(3)])
```

Output:

```
['j', 'g', 'b']
['f', 'c', 'h']
['e', 'k', 'i']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]
>>> mylist = random.sample(list1, k=9)
>>> print([mylist[i:i+3] for i in range(0, 9, 3)])
```

output
`[['e', 'b', 'i'], ['k', 'h', 'd'], ['j', 'f', 'a']]`

Comment: This answer is same as Jay's. While I posted this I didn't see Jay's answer as I was busy finding my own answer.